# Using a value to compare against an array of objects to return a different value within that object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects:

```
(7) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

and an `id` value that I want to look for inside of this array of objects.

The `id = "c2a6e78d2bc34cffb08d6e17a5631467"`

then using, this `id`, I want to return to me the object that has the `id` matching the one I have. After that, I just simply want to get a different property of that object, like `object.createdAt`.

My question is: would it be possible to use `.map` over this array, and then use this `id` to return to me the one object that contains and matches this `id`? So far I've used `map`, and `filter` but maybe I'm using this the wrong way...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
var myDesiredObject = myData.find(element => element.id == myDesiredId);
```

Comment: OH Wow. I was using it incorrectly. Thank you. Will mark as answer.

Answer (score 3):

> would it be possible to use .map over this array, and then use this id
>   to return to me the one object that contains and matches this id?

No, it would not be possible (or its usage wouldn't be the proper one) because [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

> creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on
>   every element in the calling array

In this case it would create an array with the properties `createdAt` instead of objects with all the properties (including the `id` which is necessary to be checked). So you could not pick up the correct object based on the `id` property.

Instead use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), which

> returns the value of the first element in the array that satisfies the
>   provided testing function. Otherwise undefined is returned

Like this:

`var obj = array.find(o => o.id === "c2a6e78d2bc34cffb08d6e17a5631467");`

Now in `obj` you  have the object with the `id` equals to `c2a6e78d2bc34cffb08d6e17a5631467`. You can check if the object is not `undefined` (it was found) and then access its properties as you wish.

`console.log(obj ? obj.createdAt : "not found");`

```js
var array = [{
    id: "c2a6e78d2bc34cffb08d6e17a5631467",
    createdAt: '2017-01-02'
  },
  {
    id: "some-other-id",
    createdAt: '2017-01-03'
  },
  {
    id: "some-other-id-2",
    createdAt: '2017-01-03'
  },
];

var obj = array.find(o => o.id === "c2a6e78d2bc34cffb08d6e17a5631467");
console.log(obj ? obj.createdAt : "not found");
```